# Haskell: using foldl to cascade functions

Tags: haskell, lambda

So here I have singleton list

```
[([("*" "1"),("/" "5"),("*" "10")],"")]
```

I have to take the `fst $ head` of it which is

```
[("*" "1"),("/" "5"),("*" "10")]
```

Combine it with a simple string `"5"`, and transform it into

```
(("*" "10") (("/" "5") (("* "1") "5")))
```

I know this would involve either `foldl` or `foldr`, but I just cant get it right...

This is for a parser project, I could post all the background information, but that would be too much.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

this is Haskell btw

Ah, figured this one out

```
> prods =  do left <- term       
>             right <- many (mul `mplus` div `mplus` mod)
>             return (foldl (\l r -> Call r l) left right)
```

Don't read too much into it, basically it takes the `5 * 1 / 5 *10` and convert them into `((* 10) ((/ 5) ((* 1) 5)))`

Comment: Is the final result actually meant to be: `(("*", "10"), (("/", "5"), (("*", "1"), "5")))`?

Comment: nope, you see it as `((* 10) ((/ 5) ((* 1) 5)))` which comes out to be  10

Comment: It is extremely unclear what your "singleton list" is, exactly. `("*" "1")` is *not* valid Haskell, so it's hard to know how to answer your question since it is unclear what we are working with.

Answer (score 1):

`foldl` takes a starting value and works from the outermost constructor in, `foldr` takes a starting value and works from the innermost constructor out.

```
[1,2,3] -- is just syntactic sugar for 
1:2:3:[] -- or
1:(2:(3:[])) -- or 
cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 [])) where cons a as = a:as
```

One easy way to think of `foldr` is that

```
foldr f z (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 []))) = f 1 (f 2 (f 3 z))
```

`foldr` just substitutes f for cons and z for []

`foldl` inverts the data structure, turning it inside out.

```
foldl f z (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 []))) = f (f (f z 1) 2) 3
```

So can you see why you'll need `foldl`?

You'll still need to convert your operator strings (`"*"`, `"+"`, `"/"`) to functions, and your number strings to numbers, since `"/" "3" "4"` isn't legal haskell application.

Comment: he seems to want to apply it in the opposite order: `f 3 (f 2 (f 1 z))`

Comment: @newacct: Thanks.  That's what I get for using SO on my phone.